# phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner crashes on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I want to post this Q&A here as I see many people having this issue and the phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner github repo is now readonly, so can't post to issues there. I've been having an issue where I install the plugin in an Android 10 app, and when I call cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan() it pops up a permissions dialog and then the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the plugin by default calls for the Android compatibility library v4.27, so I'd get this line in platforms/android/project.properties:

`cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:27.+`

I solved by adding the androidx-adapter plugin:

```
cordova plugin -d add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Now that line in platforms/android/project.properties is:

```
cordova.system.library.2=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
```

And the plugin works as expected and does not crash the app. Hope this helps someone else!